# How to set limited access to some portion of code in Git?

Tags: git

I have a few developers on my team and I need to restrict each one access to some portions of our codes. we are using self-hosted version of GitLab.

For example I want to limit **programmer1** to just has access to **folder1** and won't be able to see or clone folder2 contents to his machine.

```
[RootFolder]
    -- folder1
         -- source.php
    -- folder2
         -- file.php
         -- image.jpg
```

Should I use branch or what?

Answer (score 1):

If the access controls for two directories are different, then your best bet is to put each in a separate git repository and control access at the repo level.